# C# hide form2 and reopen it without override

Tags: c#, forms, show-hide

Helo,
I have 2 forms: `form1` and `form2`.
When I press a button in form1, I want to open `form2` and the `form1` to be still visible.

code in form1:

```
private void button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 form2 form = new form2();   
 form.Show();
}
```

When I press [x] (close button) in `form2`, I want to hide it.

code in form2:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) 
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        Hide();
    }
}
```

The problem is when I press again button1 from `form1`. It opens `form2`, but like it wasn't hidden, it opens it like the first time. I don't want to close `form2` because it is a timer which is counting while the form is hidden. How can I hide `form2` when I press [x], and then when I press again button1 to reappear, not to reopen like first time?
Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `form2 form = new form2()` you create another instance of it, so you gotta save that instance and use the same:

```
private Form form;
private void button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(form==null)
         form = new Form2();

     form.Show();
}
```

Comment: ok, I understand, but I have an error when I press again the button in form1. Error: "cannot acces a disposed object" and it appears at form.Show(); in form1

Comment: i believe your form2 instance should not be disposed if you are really doing what you said in your question, that is, setting `FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel = true` and calling `Form.Hide()`

Comment: So I must change something in form2 formclosing? There is my problem? Believe me, I dit a lot of research into this issue, and I've tried in many ways so far.

Comment: @RuslanPopescu : Are you sure that you actually have subscribed to the `FormClosing` event? Your code should work unless you just copied a FormClosing method in there (because copy-pasting isn't enough).

Comment: In form 2 is what I wrote in my question